# Lazy Load data from Firebase Angular Material Table App

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material, database-performance

I use Angular Cli, AngularFire2 and Firebase.

I use the angular hardware table that works like a charm with small volume data but when I switch to a number of 300,000 objects, my application is totally slowing down, or even bug ...

Voice my data:

```
{
    "rpps": [

        {
            "IdentifiantPP": "10101553021",
            "Prenom": "PAULINE",
            "Nom": "DEROT",
            "Libellesavoir": "-",
            "MSS": "-"
        },
        {
            "IdentifiantPP": "10101553039",
            "Prenom": "PAULINE",
            "Nom": "LEMOINE",
            "Libellesavoir": "-",
            "MSS": "-"
        },

...


    ]
}
```

Here is my code

//Service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import DataSnapshot = firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import { Observable, interval, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';


import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class AnnuairesService {

medecins: AngularFireList<any>;

constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {this.medecins = database.list('rpps');  }

getMedecins() { return this.medecins.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.val();
    const key = a.payload.key;
    return {key, ...data };
  });
})); }

}
```

Component.ts

```
export class MedListComponent   {

  Medecin = {
IdentifiantPP: '',
Prenom: '',
Nom: '',
Libellesavoir: '',
MSS: ''

   }

displayedColumns = [
'IdentifiantPP',
'Prenom',
'Nom',
'Libellesavoir',
'MSS'];

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngAfterViewInit() {this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;}


ngOnInit(){ return this.annuairesService.getMedecins().subscribe(res => this.dataSource.data = res);}

constructor( private annuairesService: AnnuairesService, private router: Router, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {}
```

I think there must be solutions .. Is this problem recurring? I did not find topics on it.

[image]

Comment: Can you run the performance tool in chrome when you're loading? It should show you if the slow down is from scripting or rendering. Either way, you'll likely have to look at lazy loading or staggering the loading of the data from firebase.

Comment: @jakhicks I added the screenshot of lazy load. I think it's the "for each"..

Comment: I think your best bet is to reduce the number of items you're dealing with at a time. Does the api you have support pagination? You could request say, 50 at a time, or however many would be visible on screen at a time. When you scroll, request more.

Comment: Yes i have a pagination but i have search too... You think that it is possible ?

Comment: There are some libraries that on item destroying when they're out of view - github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll . I don't have an example of an implementation for exactly what you're trying to do.It's possible for sure though!

Comment: Sorry, you're using newer angular.. there's an updated lib - https://github.com/dhilt/ngx-ui-scroll

Comment: thanks. i go to work